# Does TypeScript not ensure a Promise is resolved with the correct type?

Tags: typescript

This compiles without error in TypeScript 2.1.5:

```
function promiseANumber(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve('definitely not a number'));
}
```

I would expect an error to be reported, since the resolve function is called with a string instead of a number, as per the type definition.

Why is this type mismatch not caught and reported by TypeScript's compiler?

---

## Edit 1

Looking at this a bit more, using an async function definition instead, the compiler correctly reports the type mismatch. So this:

```
async function promiseANumber(): Promise<number> {
    return 'definitely not a number';
}
```

gives

```
error TS2322: Type '"definitely not a number"' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Why do these cases behave differently?

---

## Edit 2

It looks like the way to make the compiler correctly catch this it to explicitly tell it which type of promise you're returning. So this is sufficient:

```
function promiseANumber() {
    return new Promise<number>(resolve => resolve('definitely not a number'));
}
```

which the compiler now complains about:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '"definitely not a number"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | Thenable<number>'.
```

I suppose my question is now, why can't the compiler infer this, given the definition I gave at the beginning of this question?

---

## Edit 3

Happily, TypeScript 2.4 now indicates the correct error for my original code! It's due to it now supporting [return types as inference targets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/#return-types-as-inference-targets). That announcement even has a code sample very similar to the example I gave initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case...

```
function promiseANumber(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve('definitely not a number'));
}
```

...the reason why resolve does not expect `number` is because it's specified as being `{}` when writing `new Promise(...)` because that's the default type of `new Promise()`. The compiler then allows the assignment for `Promise<{}>` to `Promise<number>`... that itself is questionable.

In this case...

```
async function promiseANumber(): Promise<number> {
    // type returned is Promise<string>, doesn't match Promise<number>
    return 'definitely not a number';
}
```

...the type returned is `Promise<string>` and that doesn't match `Promise<number>` so the compiler throws an error.

---

In your example with the promise, you can tell the compiler to define the promise as `Promise<number>` by doing:

```
function promiseANumber(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise<number>(resolve => resolve('definitely not a number'));
}
```

...which will cause a compile error because `string` is not assignable to `number`.

Comment: In your first example, you could explicitly write the type, i.e., `const myPromise: Promise<number> = ...`. That's then equivalent to my first example in my question. But that still doesn't seem to help the compiler. Why?

Comment: I see, thanks. It's a shame that the compiler doesn't infer that the returned promise is a Promise<number> based on the surrounding function's signature. Is that technically impossible, for some reason, or just a current limitation of TypeScript?